Installing MSIX applications to same app location
I am in the process of trying to convert installers for a desktop application from MSI to MSIX.    The conversion of the main application was successful.   When installing to a local Windows environment, it installs to C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.   However, it appears that I cannot precisely install to a specific subfolder name as indicated by this question - How to change install location of MSIX folder.
My problem is that I am hoping to convert multiple MSI installers to an MSIX package.   The core installation installs to BaseFolder and multiple other installations install to the BaseFolder\Plugins\ folder.    Previously these installations could occur independently as long as the core software is installed first to BaseFolder.
Is it possible to install multiple MSIX packages to the same app (folder) in Windows or virtual environments?    I know that I can make an MSIX bundle which will combine multiple MSIX into a bundle, which I presume would install to a common location.
If I have two applications in an MSIX bundle, do they install into a common folder?
Is there any other way that I can install multiple MSIX packages to a common app folder besides using an MSIX bundle?   There is MSIX app attach for Azure but is there an approach for Windows or other virtual environments?

you are converting your desktop or W32 application to a Windows store application. That includes installation to the Windows apps folder. It is (afaik) part of the Windows store application policy.

I am referring to the same subfolder under WindowsApps.    I was hoping to install the software files from the extension MSIX packages in the same WindowsApps subfolder as the core application MSIX.

if you want your apps to be installed all in the same folder, you have to put them all into one MSIX. If you just need a way to communicate from one app to another, you should have a look at the publisherCacheFolder. You can share data through that location.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder?view=winrt-26100
